# How to add rounded borders on a a:hover in ul li list?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where the `li` width changes in my navigation depending on the width/length of the link in my navigation `ul li` list. I am trying to add a rounded-border background image to each of the `li` elements, yet since each one is different in size, I am lost on how to implement this.

How can I create a background image that will change in width with rounded borders for each of my `li` links? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Future way

**Pros**: easy and simple
**Cons**: non IE compatible

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft  / -webkit-border-top-left-radius
-moz-border-radius-topright / -webkit-border-top-right-radius
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft / -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius
-moz-border-radius-bottomright / -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius
```

### Javascript way

**Pros**: Simple
**Cons**: Do not work if javascript is turned off

Use [Jquery](http://jquery.com) and the [JQuery Corner plug-in](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#menuItem1").hover(function(){
       $('#menuItem1').corner(); 
});
</script>
```

### Pure CSS way

As described in http://blog.benogle.com/2009/04/29/css-round-corners/
**Pros**: Pure css
**Cons**: Add lots of unneeded markup

```
.b1f, .b2f, .b3f, .b4f{font-size:1px; overflow:hidden; display:block;}
.b1f {height:1px; background:#ddd; margin:0 5px;}
.b2f {height:1px; background:#ddd; margin:0 3px;}
.b3f {height:1px; background:#ddd; margin:0 2px;}
.b4f {height:2px; background:#ddd; margin:0 1px;}
.contentf {background: #ddd;}
.contentf div {margin-left: 5px;}


<b class="b1f"></b><b class="b2f"></b><b class="b3f"></b><b class="b4f"></b>
    <div class="contentf">
        <div>Round FILL!!</div>
    </div>
<b class="b4f"></b><b class="b3f"></b><b class="b2f"></b><b class="b1f"></b>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest starting with defining the [CSS3 rounded corners](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) styles (see also [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/)).  In the long run every browser should support this.

As a fallback mechanism you could use background images with the [sliding door technique](http://kailoon.com/css-sliding-door-using-only-1-image/).

Comment: DD_roundies (http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) is excellent for adding border-radius to IE.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the size of a background image is not possible without heavy Javascript and possibly even server-side stuff.
Two workaround ideas (both not tested):

CSS 2 only:
You could give the li "position: relative" and then position a DIV or other element with rounded corners and "position :absolute" within it. Give it "left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px" so it should always be as large as the li. To avoid the content being overlaid by the element, give the content "position: relative" and a z-index.

Cross browser code swamp:

Give the li position:relative and position four rounded corner images using "position:absolute" and "left:0px;top:0px", "right:0px;top:0px" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique I "borrowed"  that doesn't require images!:

http://blog.benogle.com/2009/04/29/css-round-corners/

He fully explains the technique so you know how he does it.

Comment: That uses a lot of extra, non-semantic markup. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that will be readily compatible with all browsers everywhere is slicing your background image up and making the corners their own little images.